# The possible outcomes for tossing a Loonie, Toonie and quarter consecutively

Tags: probability

Winston tosses a Loonie, a Toonie and a quarter, one after the other. In how many different ways can they land? Use a tree diagram to answer. (Note that the Loonies, Toonies and quarters are variables to be included in your tree diagram!)
Update: For those unaware, Loonies are Toonies are simply Canadian coins.
Toonie = $2

Loonie = $1

Comment: Presumably loonies, toonies, and quarters all have a side that is referred to as "heads" and the opposite side is referred to as "tails" or otherwise can have their sides arbitrarily labeled "side A" and "side B."  Pick which outcome occurred for the loonie.  Pick which outcome occurred for the toonie.  Pick which outcome occurred for the quarter.  Apply multiplication principle and reach a conclusion.  To draw the tree diagram, at each step described before, draw branches to indicate which option was selected.  Be sure to label each branch point, branch, and leaf.

Comment: Eight ends of final branches, perhaps labeled HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, and four more. First branching for Loonie, 2nd for Toonie, 3rd for quarter.

Comment: @JMoravitz [Canadian coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coins_of_the_Canadian_dollar#Specifications) have Queen Elizabeth's head on the obverse